# When I graph $y=x^{1/2}$ why does it only show the positive y values.

Tags: graphing-functions, exponentiation, radicals

I understand the reason for $y=\sqrt{x}$. I've been told that the radical symbol gives out the positive answer. But $y=x^{1/2}$ doesn't use a radical symbol, and it still only shows the positive y values.

Comment: Try graphing it as $y^2 = x$.

Comment: That's because $x^{1/2}$ is still the positive value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to know what software package you are using here.

I tried it myself using GeoGebra, and I had the same as you: entering the formula "y=x^(1/2)" in the formula entry field did indeed yield a graph with positive $y$ only.

However, when I entered "y^2 = x" in that field, it generated both branches of the relation.

There is considerable confusion and individual taste as to exactly what is meant by $x^{1/2}$.

When in the field of complex analysis, the understanding is:
$$z^{1/n} = \{r^{1/n} (\cos(\theta + 2 \pi k / n) + i \sin (\theta + 2 \pi  k / n)): k \in \{0,1,2,…,n−1\}\}$$

from which, restricting to the real number line, you would expect $x^{1/2} = \pm \sqrt x$.

But it seems that this may not be the generally understood case. I don't know why this is and I disagree with it, as a philosophical position. But don't take my word for it, as my opinions and ideas differ from those of mainstream mathematics in plenty of ways.

Comment: I tried it both on Desmos and on my TI-84. I can't comprehend your equation. Since you seem to know a lot about the subject, I will take your word for it. I will assume that the graphing programs think of the fraction exponent as a square root with a radical sign causing it to only show the positive values.

Comment: @ratsmisimo Apologies, I didn't know your level. The equation I gave is from the field of complex analysis, which clearly you haven't reached yet. But it's a fact that graphing software is merely a tool for illustration, and it may or may not be programmed with any degree of mathematical rigour. As there is disagreement as to whether $x^{1/2}$ is or is not "supposed" to be just the positive (or rather, "principal") value or should encompass all of them, different machines may give different results. But you can probably do what you need by (if your tool allows) giving it $y^2 = x$ to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

$x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is basically the same function as $\sqrt{x}$

So for example, take $9$, $9^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is the same as $\sqrt{9}$, which is 3

Comment: ... except that the $n$th roots of a complex number $z$ are given by $z^{1 / n} = \{r^{1 / n} (\cos (\theta + 2 \pi k/ n) + i \sin (\theta + 2 \pi k / n) ): k \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, n - 1\} \}$ and so $r^{1/2}$ *should* give both. Your answer is nothing more than "it doesn't because it's not" which doesn't help at all.